# How properly generate bootstrap grid via loop using Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I use ASP.NET MVC and bootstrap. I have many objects (>2) in collection and for each need a `<div class="col-xs-6">` but with only 2 cols in a row. How to achive this using loop?
There is 1 way but I am looking for something better:

```
@model List<Object>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName"))
{
    <div class="row">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o[i].Value)
            </div>
        </div>
        } else {
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o[i].Value)
            </div>
        }
    }
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Close the row `div` and start a new one inside the loop on every 2nd iteration

```
<div class="row">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0 && i % 2 == 0)
        {
            @:</div><div class="row"> // close and start new row
        }
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o[i].Value)
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: It's just amazing! Never knew this construction!

Comment: This is indeed amazing and the display works fine, but the output HTML doesn't have the first two wrapped in a row DIV.  It's only every subsequent row.

Comment: @WillStrohl, Yes it does (not sure what you have done differently)

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of the split method found here (which I turned into a helper method)

https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/approaches-when-rendering-list-using-bootstrap-grid-system/

and a for loop I managed to achieve the grid with indexed items

```
public static class SplitListHelper
{        
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this T[] array, int size)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < (float)array.Length / size; i++)
        {
            yield return array.Skip(i * size).Take(size);
        }
    }
}
```

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    int rowCount = 0;
    foreach (var row in Model.ToArray().Split(4))
    {
        <div class="row">
            @for (int i = 0; i < row.Count(); i++)
            {
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[rowCount + i].Name)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[rowCount + i].Selected)                    
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        rowCount += 4;
    }                       
}
```