# Razor Syntax for a C# language command

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to display 4 products on each row in bootstrap grid.

This code is running as expected in a `View` except one line of code (`@i = i-1;`).

```
@for (int i = 0; i <= Model.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        @for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (i <= Model.Count() - 1)
            { 
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>@Model[i].ItemName</h2>
                <br />
                <button style="border:none; padding:0;" OnClick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Products", new { id = Model[i].ItemID })'"><img src="@Model[i].imageUrl",  width="100" height="75" /></button><br /><br />
                <p>
                    Price: @Model[i].ItemPrice
                    Availability:<span style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">Yes</span><br />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" OnClick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Products", new { id = Model[i].ItemID })'">Learn more &raquo;</button>
                    <span style="margin-left:140px">@Html.ActionLink("Buy >>", "Index", "ShoppingCart", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })</span>
                </p>
            </div>

                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        @i = i-1;
    </div>
}
```

Can someone please guide?

Thanks.

Comment: You can not assign @variable. Its read only I think. You need use @{ i = i-1; }, because @ is a echo or print output. And you probably shouldn't use @ in for loop. Else statement is necessary here.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with both the `i++;` and `@{ i = i-1; }` lines of code? And your `if (i <= Model.Count() - 1)` line make no sense

Comment: Best guess is that you are trying to create a 4 column layout? (in which case, there are far better ways to do that)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - `View` receives a list of products (Model). I'm trying to display 4 products on each row in the browser.

Comment: Then refer [How properly generate bootstrap grid via loop using Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060808/how-properly-generate-bootstrap-grid-via-loop-using-razor/41060900#41060900) for how to do that

Comment: You can just simply use `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)`, but don't assign the `i` variable as `@i` because `@` prefix intended to projecting output into view.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply make your iteration over blocks of 4 :

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count() / 4; i++)
{
    if (i < (Model.Count() / 4) || (4 * i) < Model.Count())
    {
    <div class="row">
        @for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h2>@Model[(i * 4) + j].ItemName</h2>
                    <br />
                    <button style="border:none; padding:0;" OnClick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Products", new { id = Model[(i * 4) + j].ItemID })'"><img src="@Model[(i * 4) + j].imageUrl" , width="100" height="75" /></button><br /><br />
                    <p>
                        Price: @Model[(i * 4) + j].ItemPrice
                        Availability:<span style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">Yes</span><br />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" OnClick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Products", new { id = Model[(i * 4) + j].ItemID })'">Learn more &raquo;</button>
                        <span style="margin-left:140px">@Html.ActionLink("Buy >>", "Index", "ShoppingCart", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })</span>
                    </p>
                </div>

        }

    </div>
    }
}
```

** Note that if you want to put 4 elements in a Bootstrap row, you should use col-md-3 not 4!

Comment: Actually you should be aware of J parameter in cases that it would be less than 4, for example if you have 5 elements and I variable is 1, so there is only 1 record in the second iteration for J.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for display 4 products on each row in bootstrap grid

```
   @{
  int index = 0;
 }
 @foreach (var item in @Model)
 {
   if (index % 4 == 0)
   {
      @:  <div class="row">
   }

   <div class="col-md-3">

     <h2>@item.ItemName</h2>
            <br />
            <button style="border:none; padding:0;" OnClick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Products", new { id = item.ItemID })'"><img src="@item.imageUrl",  width="100" height="75" /></button><br /><br />
            <p>
                Price: @item.ItemPrice
                Availability:<span style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">Yes</span><br />
            </p>
            <p>
                <button class="btn btn-default" OnClick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Products", new { id = item.ItemID })'">Learn more &raquo;</button>
                <span style="margin-left:140px">@Html.ActionLink("Buy >>", "Index", "ShoppingCart", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })</span>
            </p>
   </div>

   if (index % 4 == 0)
   {
      @:     </div>
   }        

   index++;
}
```